# Non-blocking UI while Search/Sort/Filter operations

Tags: javascript, performance, user-interface, scheduling, web-worker

I have a large list of items (3000 - 5000) to display. The user may filter / sort them in order to display only a particular subset. My initial implementation was essentially:

```
import { filterItems, sortItems }

const items = [...];
const results = flow([
  filterItems,
  sortItems,
])(items);
```

...where the imported functions are basically wrappers around array `.sort` and `.filter` ( + a lot of custom options). This works, but it blocks the UI. I'm looking for recommendations on how to proceed while still utilizing these two core functions. I feel I've two general paths:

---

1) JS scheduling / time-slicing

How might I break up the filter/sort functions to accommodate this? I've tried using something like this [queue scheduler](https://github.com/justinfagnani/queue-scheduler) + *slightly modifying* `sortItems` to yield each loop, but as the whole thing is in a `sort` callback it does not work:

```
// simplified for brevity
function sortItems(items, context) { // context comes from a Scheduler
  return items.sort((a, b) => {
    context.yield();                 // can I return control back here ...?
    return (+!a - +!b) || (a > b ? 1 : -1);
  }
}
```

I want to try other variations here on this theme (ie. setTimeout, rAF etc) but as there is no "unit of work" or "step" function, I'm wondering if I'd need to implement my own sorting/filtering using a `for` loop and not rely on `[].filter` / `[].sort`. Are there performance implications to this?

---

2) Web-worker

This is another option. However, for maintainability I'd prefer to re-use `filterItems`, `sortItems` without having to copy/paste them into a worker file. Is there a way to do this? I'm aware of inlining the worker i.e. using URL + Blobs, or [Greenlet](https://github.com/developit/greenlet)... but I've not been able to get it to work.

```
let results = greenlet(async (items) => {
  const filtered = filterItems(items); // <-- i realize this is not possible (and doesn't work)
  ...
});
```

Relatedly - is it possible to somehow use an imported function via `toString()` in a worker?  i.e `filterItems.toString()` + an inlining method?

---

If you have general advice or can share experience in similar ventures (or if i'm doing it wrong), please let me know. Thanks in advance ~

Comment: One rather easy solution is to chunk your items and put a `setTimeout` in between each chunk sort and filter.

Comment: @norbertpy - yeah I would love to do that, however I’m not sure I can given that there is no “chunkable” function — array sort (and filter) runs on the entirety of the `items` array. I could roll my own but wasn’t sure if that was optimal

Comment: Filtering and sorting 5000 items should not block your UI. Either there is something wrong happening in these operations, that should rather be fixed, either the culprit is not here. Anyway, check your dev tools performance tab and try to find what's really blocking (I'd personaly place my bet on the rendering step rather than the simple filter and sort).

Comment: ha yeah, it's not rendering performance unfortunately (although it's a factor). i'm paginating the results, and have tried just dumping content as text as well. i can see in the dev tools performance tab where the slowdown is, and it's predominantly sorting

Comment: @wes, filtering can be done on a single item and then there is merge sort to do on chunks but if you can provide a runnable code people can help you a lot easier.

Comment: yeah you're right, thanks. i'll try to make a reduced test case and work backwards from there